# Can the AWS Schema Conversion Tool Connect to Azure

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-rds, aws-sct

I am trying to migrate a database from a Microsoft SQL Server on Azure to an Amazon Aurora Database on AWS. Amazon provides a tool called the AWS Schema Conversion tool that is supposed to be able to convert a Microsoft SQL schema to Amazon Aurora.

I've been able to connect to my Aurora database, but I can't seem to connect to the Microsoft SQL database.

This is the connection info that I'm using:

> - **Server name:** 'server name'.database.secure.windows.net
> - **Server port:** 1433
> - **Instance name:** *left blank*
> - **User name:** 'user name'@'server name'
> - **Password:** 'password'

However, I keep getting the following error:

> The specified account (sqldt) does not have sufficient privileges for working with the following object(s):

Then it lists all of my databases.

The username and password that I'm using is the administrative account for the database. Any idea why it wouldn't have the necessary permissions?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SCT tool doesn't list Azure SQL Database as a supported source. The metadata calls are slightly different for enumerating objects between SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. AWS would need to address this in a future release.
Regards,
Bill Ramos